# PHP file not found error but it is including the file?

Tags: php

I have the following code to include a file that runs some SQL and other code

```
if (isset($_GET["vpnadd"])) {
echo "Swapping to VPN<br />";
$filename = '/home153/sub002/sc00083-LGVN/xxx.co.uk/addmyfile.php';
require $filename;

}
```

However, when I run the code, it gives an error of: error: No such file or directory

But, it does actually run the file and inserts a database record so I am not sure why it gives the file error?

Comment: Try a relative path instead, and see if it produces the same error.

Comment: Sounds more like there's some file being included within the addmyfile.php script. If addmyfile wasn't locatable/readable, `require` would kill the script outright. it wouldn't load the file partially and then kill it. It either gets required, or nothing happens at all.

Comment: post your directory structure

Comment: That's the problem. The relative path doesn;t work as I'm not sure where it's relative to. I'm running a page that uses PHP code from a plugin stored in db to run SQL code from an included php file. The relative is either relative to the plugin or to the page but I'm not sure.

Comment: @user1898525 Sorry, can't help you there without seeing more. Try a different absolute path then, i.e. `$filename = '/addmyfile.php';` if the file is located in your root.

Comment: Try replacing `$filename = '/home153/sub002/sc00083-LGVN/xxx.co.uk/addmyfile.php';` with `dirname(__FILE__) . '/addmyfile.php';`

Comment: echo substr(str_replace('\', '/', realpath(dirname(FILE))), strlen(str_replace('\', '/', realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']))));

$dir = './'; $files1 = scandir($dir); print_r($files1);

when I do the above it lists the file addmyfile.php in the directory but when I then do $filename = './addmyfile.php'; require $filename;

same error, file not found. I don;t have any other require commands in my scripts.

Comment: dirname gives this: /mounted-storage/home153/sub002/sc00345-LGVN/mysite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/addmyfile.php But that is not the correct location. addmyfile.php is in the root no error reported in the require command that time but it didn;t run the SQL script though